# android - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the text of the navigation drawer activity from the fetched data on my database, but when i try to do so, it throws the following error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Am I missing something or did I do something wrong in my code?

```
public void fetchDb(){
    String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EMAIL");

    TextView txtName = findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    TextView txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.emailText);
    String name, ema;

    DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    newDb = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = newDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = \'" + email+"\'", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            name = c.getString(1);
            ema = c.getString(2);

            txtName.setText(name);
            txtEmail.setText(ema);

        } while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    newDb.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your layout.xml?

Comment: check your textview id

Comment: my text view names are correct, and are in the nav_header_main_menu.xml layout.

Comment: the fetchDb() method is in the MainMenu.java class

Comment: paste your xml also

Comment: you need to access your TextViews with your Nav_View reference , something like ..

navView.findVIewById(R.id.yourText);

Comment: @IvanAldwinA.Cristobal Null pointer occurs if you access any method/variable of a class without initializing it .......

Comment: Where did you call `setContentView`? And share the layout as well.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Null pointer try to say that the textview is null. That can happen beacause the findviewbyid is not matching with the right one on your xml. Be sure your id matches on your xml and java file

Comment: The textviews are located on nav_header_main_menu.xml, not on activity_main_menu.xml, is it possible to edit the nav_header_main_menu text views on the MainMenu class?

Comment: you need to find it on  the view of nav_header. First create view for header and find it.
   NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View header= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        text= header.findViewById(R.id.text);

Answer (score 6):

Possibly there are two situation..
If u are using older version of Android studio then u should use this `TextView txtName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameText);`

Another possibility is that may be the layout is different where the textview is declared.

Comment: i am not using an older version, but i think it is the different layout. since the textviews i am declaring are in the nav_header_main_menu.xml file. not in the activity_main_menu.xml

Comment: Yeah..then u have to pass the navheader context to findviewbyid..
`NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.nav_name);`

Comment: Do not make assumptions as answer . First read the question .

Comment: Thanks i was missing the correct layout!